# MySQL How to SELECT data from table which recorded today?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

Use PHP and MySQL. In my table, there is date field (datetime) recorded by NOW() sql function. Example value of data in this field is    **2010-10-07 10:57:36**. How can I SELECT all data which day-month-year is today. I try to use code as below:

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE date=????
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table where DATE(date)=CURDATE()`

Comment: Kaivosukeltaja's solution might be better from performance point, though

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 6
'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: 'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: As of current moment both CURDATE() and DATE() functions are alive and kicking in MySQL from 5.0 until beta 8.0 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate for current latest version). Are you sure you're using MySQL and don't have other syntax issues in your query?

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > CURDATE();
```

`CURDATE()` will return the current date as `2011-10-07` which will be cast to `2011-10-07 00:00:00` when comparing `datetime`s to it.

Note that if you use `DATE(date) = CURDATE()` you will run a date conversion for *every* row in the table, which will be really bad for your perfomance if you have many rows and/or you need to run the query often. Also make sure you have an index on `date`, otherwise both methods will be even slower.

Comment: the semicolon might break this if you're inserting above the end of your query

Comment: 'CURDATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan: That doesn't sound like a MySQL error. Maybe you're running MSSQL? Try `GETDATE()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE DATE(fieldDate) = DATE(NOW());
```

Answer (score 2):

The `date_format` function allows you to easily switch between various granularities:

Select everything from the same day:

```
select * from table 
where date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

From the same month:

```
select * from table 
where date_format(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m');
```

From the same year:

```
select * from table 
where date_format(date, '%Y') = date_format(now(), '%Y');
```

From the same hour:

```
select * from table 
where date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

and so on.

Comment: 'date_format' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(my_date)=DATE(now())

my_date -> column name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @day = '2017-12-12' ;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN DATE(@day) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(@day), INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this it exactly works on my code(access database):

```
select * from Table t where t.column>=Date() and t.column< Date() + 1
```

Answer (score -2):

use between.

```
select * from table date between '2010-10-06' and '2010-10-08';
```

Comment: Uh..today mean the day that user open my page, not the 2010-10-08. By the way, Thanks denolk.